# Entity Framework - can't enable code first migration

Tags: frameworks, migration, entity

I am having some trouble enabling code first migration following the Microsoft Data Developer procedure at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and targeting .NET Framework 4.0

I can run the following steps without error:

- Create a new MigrationsDemo Console application
- Add the latest version of the EntityFramework NuGet package to the project.

  - Tools –> Library Package Manager –> Package Manager Console
  - Run the Install-Package EntityFramework command (This installs Entity Framework 5)

However I receive an error when attempting to run the "Enable-Migrations" command in Package Manager Console:

> Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on what I can do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Mike, did you get this sorted out? Do you remember how?

Answer (score 0):

FYI I hit this problem as well with VS 2012 and .NET framework 4.0 what helped me was this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572319/2259509 , its ridiculous but the ampersand does seem to cause this error

Answer (score 0):

`<Private>True</Private>`

For me, the above was missing from the assembly reference in the csproj file.

This means on build it isn't copied, and so cannot be seen.

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.2.1100\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Comment: FWIW I blame nuget messing with the private parameter