# Entity Framework Code First Migrations - Enable-Migrations fails

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have been trying to use code-first migrations, and had some limited success, but one of the things I got wrong was that I failed to tell it which project had the config information. It generated some classes for me, and I sort-of got it all working, but I figured that I should sort out the configuration issue and start over.

Bad mistake. Now that I've attempted to remove all the migrations stuff, I find I cannot re-install it. I've un-installed and re-installed EF 5, but when I use the `Enable-Migrations` command, I get an exception report:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not
>   resolved for member
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework,
>   Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

No matter what I do now, I can't seem to get past that. Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone else hitting this issue via Google may want to try double-checking all App.config remappings of EF to make sure they're pointed at the right version (4.4 for .NET 4, 5.0 for .NET 4.5) *and also* confirming that the project files are referencing the correct DLL. Nuget managed to screw some of that up somehow during an update, and lining it all up correctly makes the migration tool work again.

Comment: @DanFitch Thank you very much, Nuget shenanigans put in an assembly binding redirect which it didn't clear up when i was switching between versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know why this wasn't a problem from the get-go, but it turns out that the issue was caused by my having some projects targetting .NET 4.5 and some targetting .NET 4.0. This means that those projects use different versions of EF 5 (v5 versus v4.4), and I think that was causing the problem; it was attempting to load the wrong version of the DLL.

When I unloaded the projects targetting .NET 4.5 from my solution, I could use Enable-Migrations on the projects targetting .NET 4.

Answer (score 29):

This happened to me because I had a special character in the path of my project -  specifically, an ampersand *&*. I removed the ampersand and then everything worked like a charm.

Comment: thanks, great solution. The path of my project had an ampersand too, so I rename it and my problem solved.

Comment: I didn't think it was the '&' character, but it ended up it WAS in my project path.  After coming back to this issue off-and-on, removing the character from the project path did the trick.

Shouldn't this be considered a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way this problem can occur so I would like to share it here for future reference :-) .

In our case we got an invalid binding redirect in our `Web.config` file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.2.0.0" />
   <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="libs/EntityFramework.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Even though the NuGet package version is **6.2** the assembly version is still **6.0.0.0**. Using this redirect will probably not cause issues with your code, but will break the powershell EF commands as well as the `migrate.exe` tool.

The solution is either to remove the binding or using the proper version - **6.0.0.0**.

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
   <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="libs/EntityFramework.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the `migrate.exe` tool only works with older versions of Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Writing this cause maybe someday it will help someone - just had the same problem and the (stupid) issue was bad hostname at the connectionString.

Answer (score 0):

My project was receiving this error of naming convention.  MyProject.MyProject.Web, MyProject.MyProject.EntityFramework, etc.

I changed it to MyProject.MyProject2.Web, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My Project folder path had a word Q&A. As soon as I changed to QA and re-run the migrations, this issue has gone away. 
Avoid '&' character in name of any folders in the project path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which may have been caused by changing the name of the project and/or moving it in my project folder structure. It was, anyhow, solved by recreating the project and importing (add existing item) all my .cs files manually, then adding new migrations.