# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

While enabling migration for entity framework code first approach, I am getting below mentioned error. What is the issue? Please help me.

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not
>   resolved for member
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetContextType(String
>   contextTypeName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String
>   contextTypeName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Type is not resolved for member
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of:
[Entity Framework Code First Migrations - Enable-Migrations fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144827/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-enable-migrations-fails)

Also you can read here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1978562.aspx?Getting+exception+while+running+EF+Migrations+command+in+Package+Manager+Console

Comment: I did check this link - Entity Framework Code First Migrations - Enable-Migrations fails. Most people have got the resolution by removing & from their project path. Could you please let me know where to check this... I mean what project path?

Comment: Project path is path where you saved your project.
Like: D:\Project\My & Company project

Comment: Many Thanks David. It worked.