# Linqpad error with EntityFramework Custom Assembly Connection (Type is not resolved for member)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linqpad

Before my hard drive crashed, Linqpad (v4 & 5) was working fine with my assembly. Since I've reinstalled Linqpad on the new drive I can't get it to work with my current custom assembly. It works with an older version of it, but not the current one. In the image, you can see a good connection directly to an sdf file and the two other good connections are both using the older assembly. The only thing I can think of is that maybe the problem is with the latest EF 6.1.3, in the current project. I just don't know how to resolve this and any help is much appreciated, thank you!

[image: Linqpad Error with my custom assembly]

Comment: I have a similar error: Error: Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
Ef. 6.1.3

Comment: Yeah, I still haven't solved this issue. I love Linqpad but I can't use it as much as I'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connectionString. In my case I was NOT passing the namespace under which I created my EDMX. for example -

```
res://SomeNamespace.MyDataModel.csdl....
```

I created the EDMX under a subdirectory which made it inherit a namespace.

Once I added the namespace to connection string, it was working as usual.

Comment: Thank you Arpit, I wish it was that easy. but it doesn't matter what I do, I get that same error.

Comment: Does the following help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144827/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-enable-migrations-fails

Comment: @JoeAlbahari I wish it would've, thanks for the suggestion. I have two projects in the solution, one for the app and the other for the Data Model and they were not targeting the same .Net framework, but now that I made them both 4.6 and rebuilt the solution, I get the same error as above. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This comes late but maybe it helps others:

My error was actually different: UnintentionalCodeFirstException
Upon some digging it turns out I was using the wrong assembly and the wrong config file.
In our setup with have an assembly with the EF stuff, which is then use din various projects. I was using that assembly from a project alongside the appsettings.config of that project. Turns out I needed the config for the EF assembly.
Not only that, but the syntax of the connection string from it may not be supported, so what I ended up doing was to create another config file, based on the EF project one, with the required values in it.

Here's the relevant sections from my config (make sure to replace the particular personal values accordingly  (server, db, password, etc)

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MySqlSRV;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=myPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=MySqlSRV; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

I would assume that you have a similar problem in that your metadata config is wrong.